# Setup Notepad++ for Java

Tags: java, batch-file, notepad++

To use Notepad++ for Java, I created a batch file to compile and run the file:

```
@ECHO OFF
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\bin\javac.exe %1
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\bin\java.exe %1
echo.
PAUSE
@ECHO ON
```

Then to run it, in the Notepad++ 'Run' prompt (F5), I typed in: `C:\Program Files\Java\java.bat "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"`. All the file paths are correct, but nothing happens when I press "Run". How can I fix this? Thanks!

Comment: This will not work as java requires different parameters than javac! And you shouldn't waste your time with batch files, either use Ant or Maven; otherwise any decent IDE (NetBeans, Eclipse) does the work for you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put `""` around the executable so it knows to include spaces as oppose to treating the spaces as separators.

```
@ECHO OFF
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\bin\javac.exe" %1
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\bin\java.exe" %1
echo.
PAUSE
@ECHO ON
```

Answer (score 5):

Enclose the ENTIRE executable names in `"quotes"` since SPACES are seen as separators.